# how can we set tag for a CCSprite in cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2D . I want to set Tag for CCSprite but this show me error in cococs2D version 3 while i have seen Answer on Stackoverflow `[set tag]` property but it does not work form me in cocos2d Version 3 .
What I requried is I have created two different Monster and I want to find out in Collision delegate which monster has collided . 
Let me show you how I am creating Monster.

```
CCSprite *monster = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"xyz.png"];
int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int maxY = self.contentSize.height - monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int randomY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// 2
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, randomY);
monster.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, monster.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
monster.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"monsterGroup";
monster.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"monsterCollision";
[_physicsWorld addChild:monster z:1];

// 3
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int randomDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

// 4
CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:randomDuration position:CGPointMake(-monster.contentSize.width/2, randomY)];
CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
[monster runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];




- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile
{


    [monster removeFromParent];
    [projectile removeFromParent];

    score=score+1;

    return YES;
}
```

here I want to fetch CCsprite by Tag or by image i am not sure how can i recognize CCsprite in collision delegate.

Comment: tag is deprecated in version 3. Instead, use the name property (available for all nodes). You can getChildByName, removeChildByName ... etc .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you can set name property for a sprite when adding it like:

`[self addChild:(CCNode *) z:(NSInteger) name:(NSString *)]`

and then later get it by

`getChildByName`